# Adding a bookmark to a file with PyPDF2

Tags: python, pypdf

I'm trying simply to add a bookmark to an existing PDF File.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

pdf_object = open("test.pdf","rb") 
output = PdfFileWriter()
input = PdfFileReader(pdf_object)
output.addPage(input.getPage(0)) # insert page
output.addBookmark('Hello, World Bookmark', 0, parent=None) # add bookmark
```

The code runs with no error but nothing happens in my test.pdf file. Plus i don't really understand the utility of this line :

```
output.addPage(input.getPage(0)) # insert page
```

Without it i have this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36-32\driss_projects\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    output.addBookmark('Hello, World Bookmark', 0, parent=None) # add bookmark
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 705, in addBookmark
    pageRef = self.getObject(self._pages)['/Kids'][pagenum]
IndexError: list index out of range
[Finished in 0.2s]
    enter code here
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you write the file: https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileWriter.html#PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter.write ?

Comment: "enter code here"?

Comment: I know this question was asked a while ago but it apparently **still** hasn't been answered. Did the OP ever get it working? I'm currently have the same issue, and everywhere I look all I can find is how to do this with a file that you're actually creating and not how to do so with an *existing* PDF. Have you tried changing the second option in the open() method to `"wb"` instead of `"rb"`? I'm new to python (and programming in general) but I assume the `"rb"` option is short for *'read binary'* and the `"wb"` option is short for *'write binary'*, but, like I said, I'm new so don't quote me on